# ReplyError: ERR unknown command 'evalsha' (Node.js, bull)

Tags: node.js, redis, promise

I'm trying to work abound with the bull package with Redis on windows, my server is up and running but when I try to access the job it gives me an error, 
my code so far.

```
const queue = require('bull');
const jobs = new queue('jobs')

jobs.process((job, done) => {

    try {
        console.log(job)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
   })

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {

    let dat = req.query;

    jobs.add(dat).then(() => {
        console.log('done')
    }).catch(e => console.log(e))

    res.send('job done')
})
```

here is the error:

```
{ name: 'evalsha',
  args:
   [ '0a9a51ee96320953ec7bde8e63f3f060b9dac00c',
     '6',
     'bull:jobs:wait',
     'bull:jobs:paused',
     'bull:jobs:meta-paused',
     'bull:jobs:id',
     'bull:jobs:delayed',
     'bull:jobs:priority',
     'bull:jobs:',
     '',
     '__default__',
     '{"data":"muny"}',
     '{"attempts":1,"delay":0,"timestamp":1568792004594}',
     '1568792004594',
     '0',
     '0',
     '0',
     'LPUSH',
     '4fc02f94-d198-4353-b1b3-8da40399a9c5' ] } }
```

any guesses why so? 
also it's throwing unhandled promise rejection even when I've done so, is this behavior just for windows?

Comment: aizen, which version of redis are you using?

Comment: ah, I see you're too a man of culture as well, the version is 3.11.0

Comment: Are you sure you are using 3.11? Cause the stable is redis 5, and unstable is redis 2.9.x and prod proven version is 4(which was released 2 years ago). Can you check `redis-server --version` once again. Want to reconfirm.

Comment: https://redis.io/commands/evalsha it is introduced after 2.6.x make sure you have the correct version. I would recommend upgrading the redis server to check if the problem persists

Comment: yeah, I think the problem is with `redis-server`, it is 2.4.6 which is the latest version for the windows, you can check here - https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads. I presumed that could be the case, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can see, You are using `redis 2.4.6` but according to the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/evalsha):

```
EVALSHA sha1 numkeys key [key ...] arg [arg ...]
Available since 2.6.0.
```

So, that's why this error is throwing.

Now, basically if you cannot find a redis binary for windows you can download 3.2.1 from [here](https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-8-1-and-previous-versions/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with Bull but with the Redis version you have.
Upgrading Redis to a recent [stable] version helps fix this issue.

If you are on windows system and need to install a recent version of Redis.
The best, for now, is highlighted in the post: 
https://medium.com/@Renyxz/how-to-install-redis-4-0-9-on-windows-10-details-d130ef4aaa08